# Reduce content width so that next column content can be displayed right next to it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to reduce the width of the `<p></p>` element so that the `filters applied:` text and `Division` (which is the name of the filter that has been applied) are next to each other. I mean, it should look like `filters applied:` and `Division`.

[image]

This is the `HTML` code that I have at the moment:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dashamlav/nsmj0peL/4/)

If we stretch-out the output screen on Fiddle, we see the gap between `filters applied:` and `Division`.

I tried using `width: 50%`, and lower value as well for the `<div></div>`, but it did not work. I think I am missing something here.

**EDIT: JSFiddle Output**
[image]

Comment: Did you try adding padding?

Comment: @Love2Code I added the amount of padding I needed, which was `5px`. I just wanted to reduce the width of the content (blue-section) so that the content section would only contain enough space for `filters applied:` text to show up in a single line. Then the `5px` of padding would give sufficient spacing between this text, and `Divisions` text.

Comment: No matter how you stylize you nested `p` the `div.col-sm-2` will always get 2 units of `div.row` parents width so, to work around your exact question you should add this **inline-style** to `p`: `width: fit-content; margin:0;` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezhupa99/w1o5n9ca/)

Comment: @ezhupa99 It somehow did not work. I have added the output what I am seeing in the question as an Edit. Kindly check.

Comment: @Dashamlav I answered for reducing the `p` width "part". The explanation of how your code was working is on the first comment I made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work without bootstrap this is the solution.

The 'filters applied: ' part is a static part that will always remain the same width.
The 'Division' part, will be filled with more than 1 filter I assume.

```css
.filter - container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 100px calc(90% - 100px) calc(10% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-container"></div>
```

[Solution link](https://jsfiddle.net/efwostq1/3/) without bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. For your required output, we have removed bootstrap grid classes (`row`,`col-*`). We have used flex utility class of bootstrap for your required structure, this solution works well also in responsive.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/pyrekLz3/3/

```css
.filter-box {
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.btn-box {
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 114px;
}

.division-box {
  width: calc(100% - 254px);
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .btn-box {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="d-flex group flex-sm-row flex-column ">
  <div class="filter-box">
    <p>filters applied:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="division-box">
    <span id="spanDivision" style="display: inline-block;" class="filter-label filter-label-pill">Divisions</span>
    <span id="spanFunction" style="display: none;" class="filter-label filter-label-pill">Function</span>
    <span id="spanLastLogin" style="display: none;" class="filter-label filter-label-pill">Last Login</span>
    <span id="spanUpdatesOpened" style="display: none;" class="filter-label filter-label-pill">Updates Opened</span>
    <span id="spanLicenseType" style="display: none;" class="filter-label filter-label-pill">License Type</span>
    <span id="spanInterests" style="display: none;" class="filter-label filter-label-pill">Interests</span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-box">
    <a id="addBtn" class="btn btn-success" title="Add User" href="javascript:;" onclick="Biomed.Admin.users.addUser('','add');"><i class="far fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add User</a>
  </div>
</div>
```